# tuple object has no attribute append (python)

Tags: python

I have two files:

animal.py has the following:

```
class Rabbit:

def __init__(self):
    self.list = [],    

def add(self, val):
    self.list.append(val)
```

ttt.py has the following:

```
from animal import Rabbit

r = Rabbit()
r.add(1)
```

I keep on getting an attributeError says tuple object has no attribute 'append'

BUT, I delcared list = []. That is not a tuple
how should I fix it ?

Comment: `list` is a type in python, try to use different variable names... eh, i guess it doesnt matter if its a class variable.

Comment: @TehTris: yet the value would still be a tuple. Attribute names do not dictate the type of the value.

Comment: was more concerned with overwriting an existing type, but realized it was a class variable, sorry :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the comma:

```
self.list = [],    
#  this comma ^
```

In Python, it is the *comma* that makes something a tuple; parentheses are only needed to disambiguate a tuple from other syntax that might also use commas.

Comment: thxxxxx...cannot believe it...lol